# Python: Can't save file/Windows Error 32

Tags: python, operating-system, wxpython

I have written a function which is called when my program is done with its job.

```
def allDone(self, event):
    dlg = wx.MessageBox("All done!", "Ask Alfred", wx.OK | wx.ICON_INFORMATION)
    os.unlink(self.fpath)
    os.rename(self.temp, self.fpath)
    self.pathBox.Clear()
```

However, its not working as expected. Its supposed to delete the original file, then rename the temp file to the original files path.

Instead, its only executing the unlink, deleting the file at self.fpath.

The exact error I get is:

```
File "G:/AskNorbert/finder.py", line 151, in allDone
os.rename(self.temp, self.fpath)
WindowsError: [Error 32] The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process
```

Comment: Check if temporary file is not closed in your program

Answer (score 0):

Make **sure** that you have called `flush()` and then `close()` on the temporary file before attempting to rename it, to ensure you are not locking it.

It is also worth calling `time.sleep(0.2)`, to give the OS time to finish anything it is doing, after the `close` and before the `rename`.

Comment: Iget this error now when I try os.close:                                     os.close(self.temp)
TypeError: an integer is required

Comment: The file shouldn't be "open". It is only being accessed via xlutils functions...its not being opened via excel...

Comment: If you have been reading it and still have the file handle it is likely to be still open.